# rename hostname using powershell script

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2

I am cloning an instance using golden image in AWS and I am trying to rename the instance using the IP address. The thing is I can clone and the variable $ipaddress contains the corresponding IP address, but I'm unable to get the hostname.

```
foreach ($key in $SystemTypes.Keys) {
  [String]$value = $SystemTypes[$key]

    #$value = $($SystemTypes[$key])
    $ipaddarray = $value.split('.')

    $ipaddress = $ipaddarray[0]+'.'+$ipaddarray[1]+'.'+$ipaddarray[2]+'.'+$ipaddarray[3]    

    Write-Host "the type is $key"
    Write-Host "the ip is  $ipaddress"
    Write-Host $value
    $object = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $ipaddress -Credential $MylocalCreds    
     $hostname = $object.__server
```

Answer (score 4):

Why are you doing this...

```
$ipaddarray = $value.split('.')

    $ipaddress = $ipaddarray[0]+'.'+$ipaddarray[1]+'.'+$ipaddarray[2]+'.'+$ipaddarray[3]
```

.. vs just using the built-in NIC/network cmdlets to get the IPA as a simple string.

```
(Get-NetIPAddress).IPv4Address
```

Getting a system hostname is a default system variable on every Windows host. Just use:

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME
```

Or

```
hostname
```

You should be able to do just what is described in the articles below.

```
Rename-Computer -NewName 'SomeHostname' -Restart
```

[Dynamically rename an AWS Windows host deployed via a syspreped AMI](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/03/20/dynamically-rename-an-aws-windows-host-deployed-via-a-syspreped-ami)

> 1. Deploy a Windows Server 2016 AMI
> 2. Connect to the Windows instance and customize it as required
> 3. Create a startup PowerShell script to set the hostname that will be invoked on boot before the unattended installation begins
> 4. Run InitializeInstance.ps1 -Schedule to register a scheduled task that initializes the instance on the next boot
> 5. Modify SysprepInstance.ps1 to replace the cmdline registry key after sysprep is complete and prior to shutdown
> 6. Run SysprepInstance.ps1 to sysprep the machine.

```
#Set my hostname based on my internal IP address
$instanceName = (((Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname).Content).split(".")[0]).replace("ip-172-31","TCG")

#Change the hostname in the unattend.xml file
$filePath = "C:\Windows\Panther\Unattend.xml"
$AnswerFile = [xml](Get-Content -Path $filePath)
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($answerFile.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("ns", $AnswerFile.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
$ComputerName = $AnswerFile.SelectSingleNode('/ns:unattend/ns:settings[@pass="specialize"]/ns:component[@name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup"]/ns:ComputerName', $ns)
$ComputerName.InnerText = $InstanceName
$AnswerFile.Save($filePath)

#Start the OOBE
Start-Process C:\windows\system32\oobe\windeploy.exe -Wait
```

[How to rename an AWS EC2 instance during provisioning using PowerShell](http://itprocentral.com/how-to-rename-an-aws-ec2-instance-during-provisioning-using-powershell)

Rename-Computer -NewName 'SomeHostname' -Restart

[How to change & verify hostname in windows server 2012 (AWS EC2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716279/how-to-change-verify-hostname-in-windows-server-2012-aws-ec2)

Method 1. Open cmd and type:
SCONFIG and you will get selection menu where #2 says Computer Name:

Method 2. From cmd type:

```
netdom renamecomputer %computername% /newname:<NewName> /reboot:0
```

Method 3. From the PowerShell console:

```
netdom renamecomputer $env:computername /newname:<NewName> /reboot:0
```

To verify the name form cmd type:

```
nbtstat -A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (where x is the ip address)
```

Another way to verify the name form cmd just type "hostname" without any parameters:

```
  hostname
```